# Retrieve the ID or name from the HTML tag using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python flask and I am trying to validate the form using the same. Below is the HTML code

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p><input type=file name=file>
     <input type=submit value=Upload id="my_id">
</form>
```

When the user clicks on upload, the request is sent to the python flask code. But what I wanted to do is, I wanted to retrieve the ID (my_id in this case) without explicitly specifying it.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        file = request.files.get('file')
```

For now I am directly specifying "file" to get the file uploaded. But I wanted to get the ID of the upload button without specifying it directly. Please help me in doing this.

Why I need this is because, I will be adding more upload options in near future. Hence if I get the ID properly, I can directly take in the file uploaded pertaining to that button.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why _"without specifying it directly"_? The point of the request data is that name:value pairs are set to the server. In the server, you specify the _name_ to read the _value_. Why would you not specify the name?

Comment: The use case is : Say I have asked the user to upload three images and I have three different function which are independent from each other. For eg: I am asking the user to upload Tiger ,Lion, cat image and I have a function for each of these animals. If the user uploads tiger, the request is sent to the python code where it reads the upload ID (which I will set the name of the animal (in this case tiger)) and I will read the tiger file if the upload button clicked has the ID tiger.

Comment: For that, it is best to use `button` tags for submitting with different values rather than a different name: `<button type="submit" name="clicked_button" value="lion">Upload</button>`. Then read the value of `clicked_button` in flask.

Comment: I think its fine. Can you please answer in a small code snippet example so that as a beginner, it would be easy for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to detect the `id` of a clicked button's tag from the server, because the id is not sent to the server. What is sent to the server is a list of `name`:`value` pairs.

So, one can create three submit buttons with different names and/or values.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Upload Lion">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Upload Tiger">
```

Then, on the server side, the clicked button can be detected:

```
if request.form['submit_button'] == "Upload Lion":
    process_lion()
elif request.form['submit_button'] == "Upload Tiger":
    process_tiger()
```

On the other hand, the `<button>` tag gives you more freedom, because you can specify a value to be sent to the server to be different from the label, for example:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_button" value="lion">Upload</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_button" value="tiger">Upload</button>
```

And then:

```
if request.form['submit_button'] == "lion":
    process_lion()
elif request.form['submit_button'] == "tiger":
    process_tiger()
```